# Будильник android, как правильно дать классу BroadcastReceiver доступ к объектам класса MainActivity

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Пишу подобие будильника под андроид, он должен будет через заданное время изменять текст в TextView, насколько я понял нужно это реализовывать в своем описании класса BroadcastReceiver и получить из него доступ к TextView в своей activity, для этого я делаю static метод в своей activity и вызываю его из BroadcastReceiver, будильник работает, но я думаю, что делаю все это неправильно и есть другой путь. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как еще можно получить доступ к TextView из BroadcastReceiver`a?

код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    static TextView showTime;
    EditText editTime;
    int str;
    final String LOG_TAG = "ml";


    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pi;
    AlarmManager am;


    static void setText(String text){
        showTime.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }


    Intent createIntent(String action, String extra) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(action,extra);
        return intent;
    }



    public void onClick(View view) {
        str = Integer.parseInt(editTime.getText().toString());
        showTime.setText("your delay is " + str + " ms");
        intent = createIntent("extra","qwerty");
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis() + str,pi);
    }
}
```

код моего класса Receiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final String LOG_TAG = "ml";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent){
        Intent r = intent;
        String s = r.getStringExtra("extra");
        MainActivity.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы делаете неправильно.

Например, если система прибьёт приложение, то при вызове `MainActivity.setText(s);` текстовое поле будет `null` и приложение упадёт. Т.е. вам надо как минимум иметь гарантию того, что активити отображается/функционирует на момент вызова метода.

Могу предложить такой вариант:

1. Создайте ещё один `BroadcastReceiver` активити.
2. В `onResume/onStart` активити зарегистрируйте ресивер
3. В `onPause/onStop` актвити отрегистрируйтесь.
4. Из вашего текущего ресивера шлите `Intent`, который будет принят ресивером из п1.

Так у вас не будет ошибок и всё будет, по идее, норм. Вот код отсюда:

```
public class ToastDisplay extends Activity {

    public static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST";

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Из первого ресивера вот так отправляйте интент для ресивера в активити:

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setAction(ToastDisplay.BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

---

Делать статические `View` поля в активити - зло. Не надо так)

Comment: А почему бы сразу первый (и единственный) ресивер не сделать в активити?

Comment: @eugeneek, потому что так при прибытии активити ресивер не будет принимать сообщения

Comment: Но ведь в этом конкретном примере ресивер ничего не делает, кроме как меняет текст в активити. Прибили активити, нечего и делать.

Comment: Я не знаю какова цель автора вопроса, засим просто предположил, что раз в заголовке будильник, то лучше так сделать, чтоб от активити не зависить